# Setting relative alias in zsh

Tags: shell, alias, zsh

I created such alias:

```
alias gopath="export GOPATH=$(pwd)"
```

But unfortunetelly it sets `GOPATH` to directory where `.zshrc` gets sourced. How to change alias to evaluate `pwd` when I actually call alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid expansion of `$(pwd)` when defining the alias, you can use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
alias gopath='export GOPATH=$(pwd)'
```

You could also escape the `$` explicitly with `\`, while still using double quotes:

```
alias gopath="export GOPATH=\$(pwd)"
```

This comes in handy if you want to expand some parts during definition and others when using the alias.

Answer (score 2):

use single quotes instead of double quotes. Variables and command substitutions are expanded inside double quotes. When you use single quotes, they're not expanded, but they'll be expanded later when the alias is substituted into the line.

```
alias gopath='export GOPATH=$(pwd)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function instead of an alias:

```
def gopath {
    export GOPATH=$(pwd)
}
```